# Simplest JQuery animated navbar with multi-level dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a navbar for a website and I need a very simple way of creating the drop-downs for 2 levels going from the main bar to a drop-down list with a further drop-down level.

I'm using JQuery with no extra plugins.

By "Simplest", I mean with the fewest lines of code and the fewest variables and so the fastest loading time.

I have tried using the hover() event but this does not seem to work.

Here is an example of the HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
           <ul class="sub">
               <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a>
                   <ul class="sub2">
                       <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Ideally, hovering over "Link 2" will have the child list slide down, and hovering over "Sub 1" will have the child list slide down next to it.

Also, I'm using percentages for most of the dimensions so it would be really useful if this scaled the same way.

If any more information is needed then ask before down-voting please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best jQuery is no jQuery.

```css
.menu input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.menu label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.menu label:after {
  content: '...';
}
.sub {
  display: none;
}
.menu label:hover+input+.sub,
.menu input:checked+.sub,
.sub:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
       <li>
           <label for="menu-2">Link 2</label>
           <input type="checkbox" id="menu-2" />
           <ul class="sub">
               <li>
                   <label for="menu-2-1">Sub 1</label>
                   <input type="checkbox" id="menu-2-1" />
                   <ul class="sub">
                       <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Add further CSS as necessary.

Comment: This works, but can it not only be animated, but also work on hover instead of a mouse click as the links themselves will go to other pages.

Comment: I've added hover functionality, and you can still click off the link (but on the list item) to anchor it. You can use different CSS, eg set `height:0` instead of `display:none`, and real height instead of `display:block`, then add `transition:height` to animate it.

Comment: could you demonstrate "transition:height"?

Comment: [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/gyep6o76/) but keep in mind the heights must be defined - you can't use `height:auto` with transitions.

Comment: This is looking good so far. I've made some additions to the code to make it more like what's on my end and I have noticed some problems. Namely the drop-down pushes the other content down instead of moving over it. Also, when the list expands, it expands for every element instead of just the first sub-menu.